# Devexpress RibbonForm inside SplitPanel

Tags: c#, devexpress, panel

As the title says I have a RibbonForm inside a SplitPanel, the problem here is that while I'm being able to place the form inside the panel, the form controls behave strange, specially the TextEdit control. When you try to place the caret between two characters, you can't, instead the whole text is selected. This is what I have

```
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
 frm2.TopLevel = false;
 frm2.Parent = this; 
 frm2.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
 frm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

 splContainer.Panel2.Controls.Add(frm2);

 frm2.Show();
 frm2.BringToFront();
```

I've tried using MdiParent but to no avail, the behavior stays the same.
I also read that a possible solution is to use a Dock Panel and a User Control instead of a Ribbon Form, the problem here is that I already have 20+ forms developed and fully working so I was hoping to find another solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you do it via code by adding the caret to current cursor location using keypress event..??

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BenisonSam but I think that would be more work than changing all the forms to user controls, or maybe I don't understand what you are suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exhaustive search, I've found the solution.
The key was to add a `DocumentManager`, set the main form as its `MdiParent`, and select a type of View, the next thing was to add this code:

```
 Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
 frm2.MdiParent = this; 
 frm2.Show();
```